# When trying to serialize an object whose superclass is serializable, a Not Serializable Exception is thrown. What causes this?

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization

I have a superclass that is serializable and I am trying to serialize an object of the subclass however a Not Serializable Exception is thrown. I am serializing the object in a method in the subclass and it is failing at `out.writeObject(this)`. Initially I accidentally only had the subclass implementing serializable and the serialization was working fine (though I needed some variables of the superclass which weren't serialized). From another StackOverflow question I saw that static fields may cause an issue so I changed the one static method to non-static but that did not help. Thank you.

Comment: Please update with the entire error.  Meanwhile, does the subclass include other classes, and are those classes marked as Serializable?

Comment: Agree with Andrew S - you need to look at every field in your object to make sure they are all serializable as well.  Most likely you are holding a reference to a non-serializable object in your object.

Comment: Thank you both, I had inner classes that did not implement serializable. Much appreciated.